# I cannot save the following into a RDS file in R

Tags: r, save

I am trying to save the following in my working directory:

```
ALPHABETA <- structure(c(0, 0.0094, 0.003, -0.0018, -5e-04, 0.0042, 0, -0.1842, 
-0.0672, 0.3856, -0.3433, -0.0937, 0, 0.8424, 0.5915, 0.3092, 
0.1996, 0.4278, 0, -0.0033, 0.0027, -0.0056, 0.0052, -0.0018, 
NaN, 0.9886, 0.2486, 0.6784, 0.984, 0.9863, NaN, 0.1273, 0.0211, 
0.9116, 0.3237, 0.4026), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("DGS6MO", 
"A.Adjusted", "AA.Adjusted", "AAME.Adjusted", "AAN.Adjusted", 
"AAON.Adjusted"), c("ALPHAdn", "BETAup", "BETAdn", "ALPHAup", 
"UPpval", "DNpval")))
```

However, for the `filename` portion , I am trying to use/paste the following character vector for names:

```
DATES1 <- c("199907/199912")
```

I have a loop that will go through several `DATES1` (actual DATES1 vector is much larger in length) but since this is the first iteration then:

```
ii = 1
saveRDS(ALPHABETA, file=paste0("",DATES1[ii], ".rds"))
```

I then get the following error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file '199907/199912.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

How can I save `ALPHABETA` using `saveRDS()` using my `DATES1` vector??

Comment: Are you sure the directory "199907" exists? The "/" in "199907/199912.rds" means file "19912.rs" in directory "199907" You cannot write to a directory that does not exist. You would need to create it first with `dir.create()`. If you do not want to create directories, do not use the "/" in a file name.

Comment: @MrFlick I am trying to save as `"199907/199912.rds"`  .... The directory I am trying to save to is :  ` "/Users/rimeallthetime/Desktop/R" `

Comment: Then you can't have a slash in the file name. That's simply not allowed. Change `DATES1 <- c("199907/199912")` to `DATES1 <- c("199907-199912")` or something else that doesn't have an invalid file path character in it.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for helping, you can paste your input on the answer section to approve it!

Answer (score 0):

the "/" is a special character, change it to "-" as someone suggested in the comments